# "simplify complexity"

Tags: phrases

I know it's used widely, but is the term "simplify complexity"  proper English?

I mean, you simplify things to improve them usually.  Like:

- simplify access
- simplify operations
- simplify language

But with "complexity" you really want to eliminate it, not improve it. It's like with a disease: You don't say "improve a disease" but rather "eliminate/cure" the disease, or "improve health."

Comment: I think you're making it more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: I would say *reduce the complexity.* Something can be complex to varying degrees, e.g., *somewhat/rather complex, exceedingly complex*.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Lothar,  Perhaps you might find it helpful to look at the guidance for asking questions.  There are plenty: 
 You can make clearer why you are looking by an answer by just search on the phrase to see of you can find out how this sentence is used.  I can see, for example, that many of the contexts involve computers and programming:  'where all users find hosts of overelaborate instructions.  Overcomplicated procedures feature too in all sorts of rules and regulations.  The instruction itself, "simplify" & "complexity" also, has a striking clash of contrast between the two words

Comment: It seems that you already know that *simplify complexity* is an expression that is best avoided, and are merely seeking a confirmation of that. The answer to your question is essentially, 'yeah, you are right', but posting something like that as an answer would not be in accordance with the standards of this site. (Incidentally, the reason why saying *simplify complexity* is a bad idea is that *simplify* already implies that what is simplified is something complex, so the expression seems evasive as to what kind of complexity is being simplified.)

Comment: Unless you're a prescriptivist, anything that's used widely is by definition proper English. Language is defined by how it's used, not by arbitrary rules. And people aren't always logical in their use of language.

Comment: It means to "make simple" a complexity. In that sense, it's okay(ish).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exactly the reason you have in mind, one would typically say *reduce the complexity,* not *simplify the complexity.*